# Ionic 4 Camera onscreen Button

Tags: ionic-framework, camera

its possible to add a button in onscreen of camera.My ionic version is 4 and cordova version is 8.Please kindly give me a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe what you are looking for. I guess you want custom UI on camera. Please refer [ionic camera preview](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview/)  plugin. And yes, one more note that for full documentation please refer ionic 3 document or github document for this plugin.